# Codeigniter Routing

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I have these URLs:

```
home/danh_muc/15
home/rao_vat/
home/chuyen_muc/15
```

How do I remove "home" in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Is 'home' a controller??
I think it couldn't be remove if it's a controller...
but if 'home' is some kind of index.php, you can try this..
http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/

Answer (score 0):

The best way depends on what exactly you want to happen. Try this:

```
// application/config/routes.php
$route['(danh_muc|rao_vat|chuyen_muc)/(:any)'] = 'home/$1/$2';
```

Or this:

```
$route['rao_vat'] = 'home/rao_vat';
$route['(danh_muc|chuyen_muc)/(:num)'] = 'home/$1/$2';
```

Or to answer it literally, this:

```
$route['danh_muc/15'] = 'home/danh_muc/15';
$route['rao_vat'] = 'home/rao_vat';
$route['chuyen_muc/15'] = 'home/chuyen_muc/15';
```

Comment: It should work if "home" is the controller. Did you try all 3?

Comment: I tried all, but it doesn't work ! I mean remove "home" in my URI strings .

Comment: I think your last example is backwards, full path is the value, the route is the key.

Comment: @jondavidjohn: Thanks, missed that somehow. The others should have worked though, I assumed he didn't want to hard-code the `15` into the route, but I wasn't sure.

Comment: @Hyun, routing won't redirect pages or magically rewrite your links, in case that's what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

most likely your CodeIgniter root directory is under /home in your website root.  Simply move the CodeIgniter application. Otherwise you using a controller named Home and this is normal.